# Fading in and fading out animations

Tags: libgdx, textures, animation, sprites

This is how I'm creating my player. Is there any way to start fading in and fading out for an amount of time when I get hit?

```
private Texture tex = Game.res.getTexture("player");

public Player(Body body) {
   TextureRegion[] sprites = new TextureRegion[1];
   sprites[0] = new TextureRegion(tex, 0, 0, 70, 96);
   sprites[1] = new TextureRegion(tex, 69, 193, 68, 93);
   animation.setFrames(sprites, 1 / 6f);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution suggested by Sebastian would work, but you'll end up with a lot of code just for a "fade out/fade in" animation.

Libgdx has built-in functionnalities for that in Scene2D, you should use them. ([Actions](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/actions/Actions.html), [Stage](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Stage.html), [Actor](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Actor.html)) That would make your code as simple as that :

```
 myPlayer.addAction(Actions.sequence(Actions.fadeOut(0.15f), Actions.fadeIn(0.15f));
```

Where myPlayer is an instance of an object extending the Actor class.

Answer (score 1):

Why not set the alpha value of the sprites directly via `sprite.setAlpha(float)`? Of course you would have to call that by your rendering method and calculate the amount of alpha alteration using `deltaTime`.

https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/Sprite.html#setAlpha-float-